# C++. Child inherits from Parent and is included as Parent attribute

Tags: c++, inheritance, parent-child, forward-declaration, circular-dependency

I have a very simple Child-Parent relationship, where OlderSon inherits from Parent and a Parent has a pointer to his OlderSon, such as:

```cpp
#ifndef PARENT_HXX
#define PARENT_HXX

#include <iostream>
#include <string>    
//#include "OlderSon.hxx"

class OlderSon;

class Parent
{
private :
    OlderSon* _os;
public  :           
    int _age;
    std::string _name;

    Parent(){
        _name="parent name";
        _age=60;
        //OlderSon* _os=new OlderSon();
    }
};

#endif //PARENT_HXX
```

And son:

```cpp
#ifndef OLDERSON_HXX
#define OLDERSON_HXX

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Parent.hxx"


class OlderSon: public Parent 
{
public:
    OlderSon(){
        _age=25;
        _name="Olderson name";
    }


 };

#endif //OLDERSON_HXX
```

However whenever I try to uncomment the line where the pointer is initialized `OlderSon* _os=new OlderSon();` I get an error message:

```
Parent.hxx: In constructor ‘Parent::Parent()’:
Parent.hxx:25:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct OlderSon’
Parent.hxx:8:7: error: forward declaration of ‘struct OlderSon’
```

I tried in different ways, namely including both .hxx or by forward declaration, but nothing seems to help. I guess it's not a very complex issue, but it is starting to be frustrating.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your son is a parent? I think maybe you should have a `Person` base class and have Person instances are `composed` with other `Person` instances to form families.

Comment: Hi, now that you point it out the concept of son/Parent does not make a lot of sense. However I tried to change the names to Son/Parent to explain it more clearly. In fact, those classes are part of a Factory method. I want to create both new CHARACTERS and new ITEMS inside a game. I created an `ObjectFactory`(as Parent), which will filter wheter an ITEM or CHARACTER wants to be created. And two subclasses `ItemFactory` and `CharacterFactory` which will be attributes of `ObjectFactory`. Then depending on the case will use the `.createObject(...)` of either `ItemFactory` or `CharacterFactory`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to filter anything. ObjectFactory should be abstract and if a user wants to create an item they should just use the ItemFactory.

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting the impossible. You can fix the bug by moving the implementation of `Parent:Parent` to the implementation file, but your code would still be disastrous.

Constructing a Parent would require constructing an OlderSon and constructing an OlderSon would require constructing a Parent too (since an OlderSon *is* a Parent). You would have infinite recursion.

You can't both have Parent's constructor call OlderSon's *and* vice-versa!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I thought that since the <code>OlderSon</code> attribute in the <code>Parent</code> class is private, it is not inherited by the <code>OlderSon</code>. I pictured it as:<br/> Instantiate <code>Parent</code> --> Instantiates <code>OlderSon</code> as a attribute of Parent but the private attribute is not inherited so it stops the recursion. I was wrong?

Comment: Those are just access restrictions. They don't make the member not exist. A derived class *is* an instance of the parent class and has all its capabilities. (And think about it -- what would that line of code then? What would happen if you executed any base class member function that accessed such a variable?)

Comment: I thought that line was creating a new data structure based on the inherited attributes only from the Parent class. Makes sense that it's just a matter of access restriction, since you actually can cast it to the Parent class. Then I'm not sure what to do implement this concept.

Comment: It's really not clear what the concept is. Is every `OlderSon` also a `Parent`? Why does every `Parent` need a pointer to an `OlderSon`?

Comment: In fact I renamed the classes to Parent/Son cause of generalitzation, they are meant to be classes of a factory method. It's about a game where I want to create new `Character`'s and `Item`. I have an `ObjectFatory` which decides in its `.createObject(ITEM/CHARACTER)` whether an `Item` or a `Character` is to be created, and has as attributes an `ItemFactory` and `CharacterFactory` subclasses of `ObjectFactory`. Then depending on whether `Item` or `Character` is to be created, the `ObjectFactory` uses the overridden method `.instantiateObject` of either `Item/Character-Factory` class.

Comment: I don't see why what you've described so far requires any classes to be derived from any other classes. You can design it so that a character is an item, if you want. Then you could derive "character" from "item". That might be handy because you can pass both items and characters as items.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting approach. Although I'll have to think about it cause the `Item` so far have an extensive enough polimorphism based on a Decorator pattern, and the Characters have also extensive polimorphism. I have to think about the implications of 'bonding' `Item` and `Character` to the same base class `Object`. Another option I believe would be to make `ObjectFactory` be directly responsible for the creation of both `Item` and `Character`, in separate methods, and not delegate the creation to inherited classes. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why not you define child pointer to as Parent * like;

```
class Parent
{
private :
    Parent* _os;
.
.
.
}
```

Since base class of child is parent.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, although it seems not to be fixing all the errors.

Comment: if you change os to pointer to Parent, you can remove opaque pointer "class OlderSon;" in parent.hxx which removes some of your errors.

Comment: But then, how can I use the methods in the `OlderSon` class? I should cast it everytime I want to use it? Also, the attributes(e.g. name, age) will be the ones of a `Parent`, not an `OlderSon`, no?

Comment: imho this is not good design take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency.
I would define abstract method of base class and implement these methods in OlderSon.

Comment: also you can define default method in parent and override the method in OlderSon. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding

Comment: Thank you for the help sardok. I ended up overriding the methods and not using circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The Parent() constructor uses a constructor for OlderSon().
But it doesn't know OlderSon, because you only forward-declarated it.
(which means: I'm gonna use a class called OlderSon, but all you (Parent.hxx) have to know is its name, because in this Header-file I'm only using a pointer to it.)
Try to implement the Parent() constructor in a cxx file where you include OlderSon.hxx

**EDIT:**

I oversaw the fact that OlderSon inherits from Parent... which results in an infinite recursion, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I in principle wanted to be able to implement it directly on a .hxx file. I think you are right about the infinite recursion as @DavidSchwartz pointed out. I'm think about how to redesign this.